# PostMan returns 405 but SoapUI returns 200 for same POST request

Tags: postman, soapui, http-status-code-405

I am having a strange behavior I am observing.  I use PostMan and until now, it always worked fine for me.

I have  POST request to http://domain/endpoint with a JSON body and BasicAuth

The same / identical request issued in:

- **PostMan** is failing in with **405 Method Not Allowed**
- **SoapUI** returns **200 OK** with response body back.

Both requests are identical. I basically copied the URI, the body and basic auth credentials from my PostMan into SoapUI request and it worked.

I also tried rewerting the process by manually copying all the details from SoapUI into Postman and the request would return 405.  Other requests in PostMan are working just fine.

I cannot share the URI, body, and credentials but they are identical on both PostMan and SoapUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason but I am finding this to be very strange behavior in PostMan if not a bug

What I found in PostMan console (when my request returns 405) is that my **POST** request to `http`, gets redirected to **GET** request to `https`:

[image]

Investigating further, I find that you have to change this behavior by going to **PostMan > your POST request > your request settings > and make sure you have turned ON "Follow original HTTP Method"** setting like:

[image]

After this change, my **POST** to `http` gets redirected to **POST** `https` request.

It is strange this this is by default OFF.  I did not have to do any of this in SoapUI.